# Как работать с libGDX, если версия openGL 1.1?

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx, intel

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При компиляции выдает такую ошибку`Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: OpenGL is not supported by the video driver.` Это из-за openGL. Можно ли как то поставить новее версию openGL? Характеристики на втором скрине.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ставьте свежие драйвера, очевидно

Comment: В следующий раз отредактируй свой первый вопрос, вместо того чтобы задавать такой же, но с дополнением.